# Is $f_a(x) = ax$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Introductory algebra course, having trouble proving this one. For monoid $(\mathbb{Z}_n, *)$ defined by multiplication mod n, for each $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, define $f:\mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ as $f_a(x) = ax$. Prove $f_a(x)$ is a homomorphism.

I'm having trouble because if it's a homomorphism, then $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, $f_a(xy)=f_a(x)*f_a(y) \Rightarrow a(xy) = axay$

That is where I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding something. That is clearly not true in general, right? Unless I did the calculations wrong, taking $a=2, n=25, x=1, y=7$ for example yields a counterexample where the the equation is not equal.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure your monoid is not additive? If you consider the multiplicative monoid, then $f_a$ is a homomorphism only if $a^2=a$.

Comment: This is the problem as stated by my professor: "For each a ∈ Zn, define αa : Zn → Zn by αa(x) = ax (using multiplication in Zn)." So that's why I thought it was using multiplication, but that was my thought as well

Comment: $\Bbb Z_n$ has two operations, $+_n$ and $*_n$, $ax$ means
$a*_n x$, uses the product $*_n$, but the monoid $\Bbb Z_n$ is additive, and the "homomorphism" is the same as the distributivity law.

Comment: Ohh gotcha, that makes more sense - thank you. Got tripped up with the notation